# Manta Evidence Folder Is Empty

Tags: git

I am looking at [Manta on Github](https://github.com/Illumina/manta/tree/master/docs/userGuide) and I ran a bit of code:

The following variables were defined in the code:

- `input_dir` is the file path to a folder with less than 10 .bams as per the limitations of Manta
- `output_dir` is the path to the output
- `MANTA_INSTALL_PATH` is the path to the Manta installation
- `reference` is the path to the reference fasta

```
    for file in ${input_dir}/*.bam
do
  # Create subdirectory named after bam file
  sub_dir=${output_dir}/$(basename ${file} .bam)
      mkdir -p ${sub_dir}
    
      # Use reference fasta path specified by user
      ${MANTA_INSTALL_PATH}/bin/configManta.py \
    --bam $file \
        --referenceFasta ${reference} \
    --runDir ${sub_dir} \
        --exome
    done

# Now run each `runWorkflow.py`

find "$output_dir" -name "runWorkflow.py" -exec {} \;
```

The run worked and each sample had a folder with the following files:

```
results  runWorkflow.py  runWorkflow.py.config.pickle  workflow.error.log.txt  workflow.exitcode.txt  workflow.warning.log.txt  workspace
```

Each `workflow.error.log.txt` had nothing in it implying the the run had been successful. Each `results` folder had 3 subfolders

```
evidence  stats  variants
```

The `stats` and `variants` folder each had outputs but the `evidence` folder had nothing. Is this normal? Should it have something in this folder? Why is this folder there in Manta if nothing is in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation on the GitHub page you linked to [has this to say](https://github.com/Illumina/manta/tree/master/docs/userGuide#generating-evidence-bams) about the `evidence` folder:

> **Generating evidence bams**
>
> Using the `--generateEvidenceBam` option, Manta can be configured to
> generate bam files of evidence reads for SVs listed in the candidate
> vcf file.
>
> It is recommended to use this option together with the --region
> option, so that the analysis is limited to relatively small genomic
> regions for debugging purposes.
>
> The evidence bam files are provided in
> `${MANTA_ANALYSIS_PATH}/results/evidence`, with a naming format
> `evidence_*.*.bam`. There is one such file for each input bam of the
> analysis, containing evidence reads of the candidate SVs identified
> from that input bam. Each read in an evidence bam keeps all
> information from the original bam, and it contains also a customized
> tag in the format:
> `ZM:Z:${MANTA_SV_ID_1}|${EVIDENCE_TYPE},${MANTA_SV_ID_2}|${EVIDENCE_TYPE}`.
> For example, `ZM:Z:MantaINV:5:0:1:0:0:0|PR|SRM,MantaDEL:5:1:2:0:0:0|SR`
>
> One read can have more than one of the three evidence types: PR for
> paired reads, SR for split reads, and SRM for split read mates. One
> read can be evidence for multiple SVs, which are separated by commas
> in the tag. Notice that the number of evidence reads for a particular
> SV in the evidence bam files could be more than the evidence counts
> (PR and SR) in the final vcf files. This is because more stringent
> criteria are applied for generating evidence counts in the final vcf
> files.

So it looks to me like you need the `--generateEvidenceBam` option to generate evidence, but that the directory `evidence` is created regardless of whether you use the option. Try running the analysis again, but using `--generateEvidenceBam` this time.

Comment: Thank you I checked the documentation again this seems to be the case. It is just an empty folder until `--generateEvidenceBam` is specified.